# Android app crashes when I click menu button

Tags: android

So everything loads fine in the app until I click the menu button then it kills the app instead of displaying information. There is no syntax errors but I do get the below run-time error
 **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at burt.example.com.MenuItemList.onViewCreated(MenuItemList.java:48)**

The code for the class I have the warning on is below

```
package burt.example.com;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.List;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class MenuItemList extends Fragment {

    public List<Item> items = itemDataProvider.items;
    public static final String ITEM_ID = "ITEM_ID";


    public MenuItemList() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_item_list, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        ItemAdapter itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(view.getContext(), R.layout.single_menu_item, items);

        ListView listView = view.findViewById(R.id.item_list);

        listView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Item item = items.get(position);
                getActivity().getIntent().putExtra(ITEM_ID, item.getId());

                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                transaction.replace(R.id.item_detail_container, new MenuItemDetail());
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();

            }
        });
    }
```

}

fragment_menu_item_list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MenuItemList" >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please post the xml file of fragment_menu_item_list?

Comment: I just added it

Comment: give an id to <ListView>. <ListView andriod:id="+id/item_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: You didnot provide an id for ListView in xml file. Please add android:id="@+id/item_list" in your xml file for ListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your xml . you need to assign a id of listview . `item_list`

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/item_list"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />
```